# How to transform a vector using a dataframe(associate table) in R language?

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

For example, I have a dataframe like this (the content of V1 is not the same as line number):

```
V1 V2 V3
1 cat animal
3 dog animal
4 apple fruit
```

And a vector like this:

```
c(4,1,3)
```

Is there an easy way to get a vector like this in R?

```
c("fruit:apple", "animal:cat", "animal:dog")
```

I tried `==`(`my_frame$V1==my_vector`) but found that can't be used for two vectors..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly more concise version:

```
my_charvec <- as.character(my_vector)
rownames(my_frame) <- my_frame$V1
apply(my_frame[my_charvec,c(3,2)],1,paste,collapse=":")
```

Here's the output:

```
            4             1             3 
"fruit:apple"  "animal:cat"  "animal:dog"
```

The 4,1,3 on the output are just names; you can ignore them if you want to.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this works:

```
## my_dat <- read.table(text="V1 V2 V3
## 1 cat animal
## 2 dog animal
## 3 apple fruit", header=T)
## 
## my_vect <- c(3,1,2)

library(qdap)  #for paste2 function
paste2(my_dat[sapply(my_vect, function(x) which(x == my_dat[, 1])), 3:2], sep=":")
## [1] "fruit:apple" "animal:cat"  "animal:dog"
```

First I match the `my_vect` with the column 1 of `my_dat` using `sapply`, `which` and `==`.  This tells the order to grab in:

```
sapply(my_vect, function(x) which(x == my_dat[, 1]))
## [1] 3 1 2
```

Then I index and grab only the last two columns in the order you requested (3rd col. then 2nd)

```
my_dat[sapply(my_vect, function(x) which(x == my_dat[, 1])), 3:2]

##       V3    V2
## 3  fruit apple
## 1 animal   cat
## 2 animal   dog
```

Then I use `paste2` from the `qdap` package to bind the columns together without specifying the specific columns (just being lazy; you could accomplish this with base `paste` by explicitly stating the vectors.

Answer (score 1):

@Firegun,how about using 'merge', like so:

```
#original data frames
df1=data.frame(V1=c(1,3,4),V2=c("cat","dog","apple"),V3=c("animal","animal","fruit"))
df2=data.frame(V1=c(4,1,3))

# just merge and don't sort (which is the default)
df3=merge(df2,df1,by.x="V1",sort=FALSE)
vec=as.vector(paste0(df3$V3,":",df3$V2))

> vec
[1] "fruit:apple" "animal:cat"  "animal:dog"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R solution, using `match` and `mapply`

```
d <- read.table(text='V1 V2 V3
1 cat animal
3 dog animal
4 apple fruit', header=TRUE)
v <- c(4,1,3)

with(d[match(v, d$V1), ], paste(V3, V2, sep=':'))
# [1] "fruit:apple" "animal:cat"  "animal:dog"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
> df<-data.frame(V1=c(1,2,3), V2=c("a","b","c"), V3=c("v", "nv", "nv"))
> v <- c(3,1,2)
> df[v,]
##   V1 V2 V3
## 3  3  c nv
## 1  1  a  v
## 2  2  b nv
> res <- as.character(apply(df[v,], 1, function(r) paste(r[3],r[2],sep=":")))
> res
## [1] "nv:c" "v:a"  "nv:b"
```

Comment: This assumes that V1 is actually in order of the rows.  While this is the case in the toy the OP was attempting to match this vector explicitly for some reason.  The OP states: `the content of V1 is not the same as line number`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base solution

```
a <- data.frame(c("cat", "dog", "apple"), c("animal", "animal", "fruit"))
v <- c(3,1,2)
apply(a[v,], 1, paste0, collapse=":")
```

Comment: This assumes that V1 is actually in order of the rows.  While this is the case in the toy the OP was attempting to match this vector explicitly for some reason.  The OP states: `the content of V1 is not the same as line number`